# Вернуть для кнопки исходное состояние через определенное время

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Подскажите, какие есть варианты. Необходимо, вернуть кнопку в исходное состояние, но через конкретно заданное время. Если делать через alarm, подскажите как? Нужно сделать так чтобы и после перезагрузки продолжало работать. Таймер, не годится. Вроде простое действие, но подскажите. Спасибо

Comment: View.postDelayed

Comment: После того как приложение закрыто, все возвращается обратно. Необходимо, чтобы работало как в фоновом режиме, так и после перезагрузки, продолжало отсчитывать время. К примеру поставил, чтобы через сутки, кнопка стала опять активной, и даже если телефон перезагрузился, все равно продолжает отсчитывать время.